# how to speed up this page

Tags: html, css

Is there any way I can speed up this webpage without too much hassle ? http://danydiop.com/node/115

It is too slow to load because it is too long...

thanks

Comment: "without too much hassle ?"  no.

Comment: and what abou paging, filtering and searching?

Comment: According to Chrome Developer Tools: http://i.imgur.com/KySxq.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, add paging to your product list, or add a feature to load the next part only when the user scrolls, like Google image search does.

You can also choose to load just a small piece of the product list and add the rest automatically after the page is loaded even when the user doesn't scroll.

Comment: haven't you noticed that the images are loaded dynamically only when scrolling, just like Google Images?

Comment: and @Darin Dimitrov So... what should I do ? The issue is the html loading and not images loading... the page is just too long. Do you know any jquery plugin to break the page into smaller pages (and having to click "See more") to load the remaining html ?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to break the product listing into multiple pages. There is simply too much information to display on that page.

You could in theory strip back the HTML used to render the page, and enable http compression on the server, but it won't help the fact that the page is simply too long.

Comment: Do you know a cool jquery plugin to create multiple pages from a single one ?

Comment: That defeats the purpose, the page will still be the same size. You need to break the page up into smaller batches on the server itself.

Answer (score 1):

1. Compress more the images
2. Enable gzip-encoding for the served pages
3. Put static files (images, CSS, js) on a cookieless domain
4. Ensure HTTP pipelining is supported by your server
5. Use CSS sprites for the images
6. In general follow the suggestions provided by google pagespeed

Comment: What you say doesn't help because the page is loaded slowly because of the html code and not the iamges (which are loaded dynamically).

Comment: @Patrick, first of all the HTML here loads in about one second. The images, on the other hand, take an awful lot. Secondly, only points 1 and 5 are specific to the images. All the rest of them are valid for all contents (HTML, CSS, JavaScript _and_ images).

Comment: Just to clarify, when I said that images take an awful lot to load I was talking about *perceived* time. Dynamically loading is the culprit because it won't load images until they're in view and this means that when you scroll you'll constantly see images that are not yet loaded. Basically, loading on demand is almost like shooting on your own foot in this case...

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear why dynamic loading is the culprit. If I disabled it, all page images would be downloaded at once and the page would be much slower.. right ?

Comment: @Patrick, in absolute terms it would be faster with dynamic loading turned off, because the browser would be able to exploit HTTP pipelining.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use a CDN

2) [Minify CSS](http://www.codebeautifier.com/)

3) [Minify JS](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html)

4) Compress images/use thumbnails and use [lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) to display close-ups.

5) Use Google's CDN for [JS libs](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/)

6) [Reduce HTTP Requests](http://www.justsearching.co.uk/xhtml/css-sprites-speed-up-your-site.html)

7) Cache your pages

Comment: If you check my page you can see I'm already doing 2, 3, 4, 6, 7. Mostly important, the slowness is not due to css and js but the longness of the html code in the page. I think the only solution is to break the page into smaller html pages and load them dynamically when the user scroll or when he clicks on a "See more" link on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the advices given by Zoomzoom83, CAFxX and GolezTrol, you may want to take a look at the YSlow Firefox Extension. It that analyses your page and offers performance advices. From their page:

> YSlow analyzes web pages and suggests ways to improve their performance based on a set of rules for high performance web pages. YSlow is a Firefox add-on integrated with the Firebug web development tool. YSlow grades web page based on one of three predefined ruleset or a user-defined ruleset. It offers suggestions for improving the page's performance, summarizes the page's components, displays statistics about the page, and provides tools for performance analysis, including Smush.it™ and JSLint.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/yslow/